# Css float right not woring

Tags: css

can somebody help me?
I have problem with position in css. I would like to move first div to the right and second div move under it (first picture).When I use **float: right** for first **div** it looks like that these components are next to each other (second picture).

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button> Button 1 </button> 
        <button> Button 2 </button> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <image></image>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody help me how css file sjhould looklike

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVOXA.png)
[how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51MaT.png)

Comment: This is a good time to study flexbox or grid, it can be the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a right align, you should use a flex box to hold the button:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex">
        <button style="margin-left: auto;"> Button 1 </button> 
        <button> Button 2 </button> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <image></image>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code, `style="width: 100%; display: flex"`make the div a horizontal container that occupies the whole row. `margin-left: auto;` on button 1 maximise the left margin of itself, hence pushing both button to the right. In this way, since the first div already occupy the whole first row, the image goes to row 2.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Better don't use floated element for layout purpose

Comment: You are right, let me edit the answer to change it to using flex

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 300px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .nav .menu {
      float: right;
    }

    .b-1 {
      width: 94%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
          <button>Button 1</button>
          <button>Button 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br /><br />

      <div class="b-1">
        <h2>HELLO</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding text explaining what you have done, and also removing the extra markup to keep it a minimal example.